# UIWebview Localization

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

On a localized Iphone (Language set to Hebrew) when we view a webpage using safari and tap on an input field we get the keyboard up with the "Next/Previous/Done" buttons in Hebrew.

When we view the same webpage using a UIWebview embedded inside our application the "Next/Previous/Done" buttons are always in English.

We were thinking that we might need to add a translation file for those fields but we do not know the keys to use.

Any pointers on this?

Edit: Started a bounty to hopefully get some pointers.

Edit: Attaching two pictures

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your info.plist you can set a value called CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations, if you check that everything should be translated to the right localized language.

Comment: The CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations work perfectly. How did you came up with this?

Comment: I also use it myself in a multi-language app I created

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be knowledgable, but have you tried creating the UIWebView in Interface Builder, then create a localization on the .xib file?

It seems the right way to go, since the keyboard pops up without app intervention; Cocoa Touch is the one to handle that. I think those extra buttons are not part of the keyboard per se, but added by the WebView.