# Problem in rendering Hebrew text in UIWebview

Tags: iphone, html, css, uiwebview, hebrew

I have some hebrew text stored in database. When I fetch & render it in UIWebview after applying some css (setting the background color and margin for the page) the text comes up fine but the problem is that If I right align the content in webview then the Hebrew content gets right aligned but actually it is not the way it is supposed to be. I mean the way RTL text should have shown. The **Full stop appears on the right hand side of the text** as shown in image below. I know that right aligning the text will not show it the way RTL text should be

Its not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856158/uiwebview-localization) and I have gone through the steps mentioned there but still no go.

[image]

I hope if someone can help me to shown the text in correct way . I can add the CSS snippet if required. Please comment if any supporting code or image is required

Comment: This actually has **nothing at all** to do with the other question you linked to. It relates only to how Hebrew should be rendered in HTML.

Comment: My suspicion is that it's right-aligned left-to-right text, so it treats the Hebrew characters the same as it would "Abc <Hebrew> def."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should either set `direction: rtl` in the CSS or add a `dir="rtl"` attribute in the HTML.

You may also need to fiddle with the `unicode-bidi` CSS attribute as well if you're embedding this text into a mixed-language paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

u need to specify dir="rtl" in html then you will get the data from right to left

Example:

```
    NSString  *htmlStringwithFont = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span style=\"font-family: %@; color:#343434;font-size: %i\" **dir=\"rtl\"**>%@</span>",
                                      font.fontName,
                                      (int) font.pointSize,
                                      content];
           webView.opaque=NO;
            [webView loadHTMLString:htmlStringwithFont baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks Mahesh, the above solution was already offered by Ken.Many Thanks