# iPhone keyboard in UIWebView, how to change the language of next/previous and done buttons

Tags: iphone, safari, keyboard, mobile-safari, translation

UIWebView's keyboard is pretty cool with its next/previous and done buttons. However, I was not able to find and change the button titles. The titles are always in english no matter in which language the system is running.

Comment: Mine change correctly when I switch the phone's language.

Comment: Sorry, I mean UIWebView not safari.

Comment: Unless you have your own keyboard designed by you which overrides stock one, your unable to change stock keyboard language (it's taken from iOS language set via Preferences > General > International).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have your own keyboard designed by you which overrides stock one, you can't do that.
Stock keyboard's language is taken from iOS language setting (via Preferences > General > International).

Comment: I don't think this is true. The first thing I did was change the device language, but regardless of the region/language settings, the buttons always come up in English. I've been fighting with this on iOS 5.1, 6, and 7. Still don't have the solution...

Comment: Havard's answer and link are correct.l Changing the device language only works if you have set the correct flag in the Info.plist.

Answer (score 5):

I have been looking for the answer to this for a while for my PhoneGap based application, and at last I found the answer here: [UIWebview Localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856158/uiwebview-localization).

The clue is to set 'CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations' to 'Yes' in your info.plist. That really made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set your own view on top of the keyboard. It is really easy after 3.2 and I have some sample code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158574/programatically-align-a-toolbar-on-top-of-the-iphone-keyboard/6022567#6022567). That means you can use your own buttons and even set localized text there.

EDIT: That was a bad answer :) Sorry, I didn't see the 'mobile-safari' tag. But in my case, I also get localized versions of the keyboard previous/next buttons.