# Android iOS webview accessibilitiy

Tags: android, ios, webview

I have an application on Android and iOS platform which is using webview to show some of the content.

My question is how can I change the voice over language of the webpage?
It seems that all of my controls in the webview are using English. Even I change the OS language.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the case, but is the desired language voice installed on your phone?

Like so:

[Change android voice](http://www.androidauthority.com/google-text-to-speech-engine-659528/)

Comment: Yeah Android is work now, but my iPhone is still just speaking "Play" on play button in audio tag. It does not change the language.

Comment: iOS the same settings descripton [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202362) maybe you wan't to set the current locale, and set a meta Information for the language on your webpage. But usually the voice over is controlled by the phones settings

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
There is a metadata call CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations [Infomation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856158/uiwebview-localization)